# Electron's behavior

Tags: electrons, double-slit-experiment, wave-particle-duality

I read in the double slit experiment which is done with electrons that they show wave-like behavior but when we have an observer the electrons change their behavior and show particle-like behavior. Are we sure about the results of this experiment? I mean what if the observer or some other things interfere with the results?

Comment: Subatomic particles (e.g.electrons) exhibit both wave and particle behavior. Which type of behavior is observed depends on the experiment. The gist is that waves and particles are our models. The electron is in reality neither, it is something else. Its behavior is in fact governed by quantum mechanics.

Comment: Absolutely, the observer "interferes with" the electron.  There is no way to observe the electron without interacting with it one way or another.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: It is always not bad to know the historical facts and to read original sources. An excerpt of this you can read in an also oration of mine about [Deflection of electrons behind edges](https://www.academia.edu/27983554/Deflection_of_electron_beams_at_edges)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, let's ask what is meant by *wave-like* behavior and *particle-like* behavior. In the case of the double-slit experiment we observe wave-like behavior when we observe interference fringes. When the experiment is changes such that these interference fringes disappear we refer to it as particle-like behavior.

So the question then becomes, when would we see interference fringes and under what circumstances would they disappear? We'll consider this question in the quantum mechanical context, but a similar discussion may be followed for the classical case. Interference (both classical and quantum mechanical) requires coherence. That means that there is a fixed relationship between the two parts of the state of the system. In this case the two parts are represented by the two paths that the particle/wave could take. Let's represent this by (ignoring normalization)
$$ |\psi\rangle=|A\rangle+|B\rangle , $$
where $A$ and $B$ represent the two slits. With the superposition as given above, we have coherence and therefore will see wave-like interference.

On the other hand, if we were to observe which slit the particle passed through then the system becomes entangled with our knowledge. One can represent it with tags (additional kets) as 
$$ |\psi'\rangle=|A\rangle|it's~in~A\rangle+|B\rangle|it's~in~B\rangle . $$
However these additional tags sits with the observer and does nto go onto the screen. So what happens on the screen is independent of these tags. Therefore we need to trace out the tags. The result becomes a mixed state
$$ \rho={\rm tr}_{tags}\{|\psi'\rangle\langle\psi'|\} = |A\rangle\langle A|+|B\rangle\langle B| . $$
For such a state there is no coherence left and therefore one does not see any interference anymore. The output now becomes particle-like.

This mechanism for destroying the coherence can happen in various ways. Whenever the individual terms in the superposition becomes entangled with something else that is not observed in the end, then one needs to trace it out. That then causes the state to become mixed.